# Bash print the number of incorrect file line

Tags: bash, loops, printing, counter

A beginner asking for help (:

So, I have a script that checks brackets in a text file and tells whether they are closed correctly. However, I also want to make my script print out the number of the incorrect line (where brackets are closed incorrectly). I have tried counting file lines and then making a nested while loop, however, it doesn't work for me at all ): Are there any simple solutions for this? I would like to leave the LINE counter if that's possible o:

```
INPUT="$1" 
count=0
LINE=0


# Check if file exists
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "file $INPUT do not exist."; exit ; }


# Count file lines and read every char
while IFS= read -r LINE
do
LINE=$(( LINE + 1 ))
     while read -n1 char
     do
     [ "$char" == "(" ] && (( count++ ))
     [ "$char" == ")" ] && (( count-- ))

     if [ "$count" -lt 0 ]
     then
          break 
     fi

done 
done < "$INPUT"


if [ "$count" -lt 0 ]
   then
echo "Found a mistake in $LINE line "
   else
echo "Everything's correct"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

- Your `read` in the inner loop consumes the input from the file, not from `LINE`.
- The line

  ```
  LINE=$(( LINE + 1 ))
  ```

  is really wrong: `LINE` is the content of the line of your file, and your trying to add `1` to it. Weird.
- Your `break` only breaks the inner loop (it should break two loops). Use `break 2` for this.

Here's a working version of your script:

```
input=$1
count=0
linenb=0

# Check if file exists
[[ -f $input ]] || { echo "Error: file $input do not exist."; exit 1; }

# Count file lines and read every char
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((++linenb))
     while read -n1 char; do
         [[ $char == '(' ]] && ((++count))
         [[ $char == ')' ]] && ((--count))
         ((count>=0)) || break 2
     done <<< "$line"
done < "$input"

if ((count<0)); then
    echo "Found a mistake in line #$linenb:"
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
else
    echo "Everything's correct"
fi
```

Note that I used more `((...))` and `[[...]]`.

I also used lowercase variable names, as your computer isn't deaf: you don't need to shout the name of the variable. (And it's nicer to the eye). And it's good practice to use lowercase variable names, as there's no chance that they clash with Bash's own variables.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I'll keep in mind what you have said (: